# Micropython - WIFI and ADC sensor not working together

Tags: python, esp32, sensors, micropython, thonny

Im using esp32 and I have an ADC sensor called "Water Sensor" which detects the water level. Basically, I want to connect to a WIFI and then upload the readings to a MQTT Broker. But I found out, that if I connect to a WIFI, the read function doesnt work. Here is the code

> ```
> from machine import ADC, Pin
> import network
> import time
>
> adc_pin = 4 
> adc = ADC(Pin(adc_pin))
>
> Wi-Fi credentials
> WIFI_SSID = "XXXXX"
> WIFI_PASSWORD = "XXXXX"
>
> def read_water_sensor(): #Reading the values
> value = adc.read()  #Here is the error
> return value 
>
> def connect_wifi(): #Connecting def
> sta_if = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF) 
> if not sta_if.isconnected():
> print("Connecting to Wi-Fi...")
> sta_if.active(True)
> sta_if.connect(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD)
> while not sta_if.isconnected():
> pass
> print("Connected to Wi-Fi")
>
> connect_wifi() #connect to the internet
> while True:
> water_value = read_water_sensor()
> print("Water sensor value:", water_value)
> time.sleep(0.1)
> ```

This is the error in Thonny micropython:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 29, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in read_water_sensor
OSError: [Errno 116] ETIMEDOUT: ESP_ERR_TIMEOUT
```

Is there another way to read the values ? Or anything else I could try to do ?

I've been trying to use time.sleep between connecting to the internet and printing out the values. I also tried to connect to internet, then disconnect and try to get a value but still nothing

Comment: Could you remove the comment `>` character? If you want to display code, use the code ``` formatting only. Also, please fix your indentation.

Comment: This is why indentation is very import for python code. You had a timeout error, so to what level of indentation your `time.sleep(0.1)` belong to?